# How to add brushes in scuplting mode or a texture?

Tags: texturing

So how do you go about adding brushes or a texture to a brush to create certain strokes?

I've made 10 different textures and it seems when I use them, I feel it doesn't recognize them.

Comment: Welcome to site! So you ask how to create new sculpt brushes ? Or how to use texture for determining the effect of the brush ? Also please include info (text, screenshots) about what have you tried with those 10 textures and what didn't work. Thanks.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/ix7J57P.png What i've tried is adding it in the brush textures on the toolbar and added it to the texture drop down in the sculpt mode.  http://i.imgur.com/rNx2pzp.png

Comment: What I see is that it only leaves a spot on the area and doesn't follow the brush. Here is the results trying to paint on the model. http://i.imgur.com/pmXccdX.png

Comment: Figured it out. Was using f brush instead of f sculpt draw..... Thanks for the help!!!